# swift gesture recognizer longpress with pinch and drag

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

hey guys Im trying to make a view appear upon longpress in the parent view and make it draggable and pinchable but as on now I can only make in draggable but the pinch doesnt work. Here is my code

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // MARK: Intializer
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    // MARK: View controller lifecycle methods    
    public override func loadView() {
        self.view = MainView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let longpressed = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longpressedAction(_:)))
        longpressed.minimumPressDuration = 0
        longpressed.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.rootView.addGestureRecognizer(longpressed)

//        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapAction(_:)))
//        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
//        self.rootView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    // MARK: Stored Properties
    private var circleView: ShapeView!

}

// MARK: - Views
extension MainVC {
    public unowned var rootView: MainView { return self.view as! MainView } // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
}

// MARK: - Action Functions
extension MainVC {

    @objc func longpressedAction(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began {
            self.addCircle(gesture: sender)

        } else if sender.state == .changed {

            let location = sender.location(in: self.view)
            self.circleView.center = CGPoint(
                x: view.center.x + (location.x - view.center.x),
                y: view.center.y + (location.y - view.center.y)
            )

        } else if sender.state == .ended{
            self.circleView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }


    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if gestureRecognizer == self.circleView.pinchRecognizer {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    @objc func pinchAction(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        print("PINCHING")
        let scale = sender.scale
        self.circleView.transform = self.circleView.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        sender.scale = 1.0
    }
}

// MARK: - Helper Function
extension MainVC {

    func addCircle(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = gesture.location(in: self.rootView)

        let pinchRecog: UIPinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinchAction(_:)))

        self.circleView = ShapeView(origin: tapPoint, pinchRecognizer: pinchRecog)
        self.circleView.pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.rootView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecog)

        self.rootView.addSubview(self.circleView)
    }
}
```

here is the view for the shape that will appear upon longpress of two fingers

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ShapeView: UIView {
    let size: CGFloat = 150.0

    var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var circlePath: UIBezierPath!
    var roundRect: CGRect!
    var pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer

    init(origin: CGPoint, pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        self.roundRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.size, height: self.size)        
        self.pinchRecognizer = pinchRecognizer
        super.init(frame: self.roundRect)
        self.center = origin

        self.circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.roundRect, cornerRadius: 10)

        self.circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        self.circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.circleLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0        

        // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
        layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayer)

//        self.initGestureRecognizers()
    }

    // We need to implement init(coder) to avoid compilation errors
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func initGestureRecognizers() {
        let pinchGR = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPinch(pinchGR:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(pinchGR)

        let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(panGR:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panGR)
    }

    @objc func didPinch(pinchGR: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        print("hahahah")
        self.superview!.bringSubview(toFront: self)

        let scale = pinchGR.scale

        self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

        pinchGR.scale = 1.0
    }

    @objc func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        self.superview!.bringSubview(toFront: self)

        var translation = panGR.translation(in: self)

        self.center.x += translation.x
        self.center.y += translation.y

        panGR.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
    }

}
```

Im currently using coordinator pattern for it and here is the repository for the codes https://github.com/aoiserizawa/kurayami/tree/master/kurayami

Answer (score 0):

it's working now after I add:

```
extension MainVC: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

to make the multiple gesture possible for long press. kindly see the updated code on my github account